# Python 3D-1D Array multiplication

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Alright, so i want to multiply a 3D array and 1D array together and then do summation like in the example below

```
A = [Array([[[100, 100, 100],
            [100, 100, 100]],

            [[100, 100, 100],
            [100, 100, 100]]]), 

    Array([[[200, 200, 200],
            [200, 200, 200]],

            [[200, 200, 200],
            [200, 200, 200]]])]

Weight = [0.25,0.75]


# A[0]*Weight[0]+A[1]*Weight[1]

C = [[[100*0.25 + 200*0.75, 100*0.25 + 200*0.75, 100*0.25 + 200*0.75],
      [100*0.25 + 200*0.75, 100*0.25 + 200*0.75, 100*0.25 + 200*0.75]],
    
     [[100*0.25 + 200*0.75, 100*0.25 + 200*0.75, 100*0.25 + 200*0.75],
      [100*0.25 + 200*0.75, 100*0.25 + 200*0.75, 100*0.25 + 200*0.75]]]
    
  = [[[175, 175, 175],
      [175, 175, 175]],
    
     [[175, 175, 175],
      [175, 175, 175]]]
```

The question is how do i do it in python? I tried to use `np.multiply`, `np.dot`, `np.matmul` but none of them seems to work as i intended. Maybe i didn't do it correctly. By the way, i also want it to be able to multiply even larger array, for example `A` Array with multiple `Array()` inside, not just 2 like in the example. And of course the length of `Weight` Array will follow the length of `A` Array. Also if possible i also wanna avoid using `for`-loop and use only `numpy` functions instead.

Comment: Can we assume that you are using numpy arrays? Did you have a look at the numpy broadcasting mechanics? https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply broadcast the values and sum them up.

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([np.array([[[100, 100, 100],
            [100, 100, 100]],

            [[100, 100, 100],
            [100, 100, 100]]]), 

    np.array([[[200, 200, 200],
            [200, 200, 200]],

            [[200, 200, 200],
            [200, 200, 200]]])])


Weight = np.array([0.25,0.75])

P = (A * Weight[:, None, None, None]).sum(0)
```

Or you can also use `einsum`. Replace the last line with -

`P = np.einsum("ijkl,i->jkl", A, Weight)`

Gives the same result.

Comment: when i use the `P = (A * Weight[:, None, None, None]).sum(0)` i got this error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple` , but if i use the `einsum` it works

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
A = np.array([np.array([[[100, 100, 100],
            [100, 100, 100]],

            [[100, 100, 100],
            [100, 100, 100]]]), 

    np.array([[[200, 200, 200],
            [200, 200, 200]],

            [[200, 200, 200],
            [200, 200, 200]]])])

Weight = np.array([0.25,0.75])
```

---

```
res = (Weight[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis] * A).sum(axis=0)
```

---

**res:**

```
array([[[175., 175., 175.],
        [175., 175., 175.]],

       [[175., 175., 175.],
        [175., 175., 175.]]])
```

you need to have shape:

**A.shape:**

```
(2, 2, 2, 3)
```

**Weight.shape:**

```
(2, 1, 1, 1)
```